# Index and primary key in large table that doesn't have an Id column

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

I'm looking for guidance on the best practice for adding indexes / primary key for the following table in SQL Server.

My goal is to maximize performance mostly on selecting data, but also in inserts.

```
IndicatorValue
(
   [IndicatorId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,  -- this is a foreign key
   [UnixTime] [bigint] NOT null,
   [Value] [decimal](15,4) NOT NULL,
   [Interval] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

The table will have over 10 million rows. Data is batch inserted between 5-10 thousand rows at a time.

I frequently query the data and retrieve the same 5-10 thousand rows at a time with SQL similar to

```
SELECT [UnixTime]
FROM [IndicatorValue]
WHERE [IndicatorId] = 'xxx GUID xxx'
  AND [Interval] = 2
ORDER BY [UnixTime]
```

or

```
SELECT [UnixTime], [Value]
FROM [IndicatorValue]
WHERE [IndicatorId] = 'xxx GUID xxx'
  AND [Interval] = 2
ORDER BY [UnixTime]
```

Based on my limited knowledge of SQL indexes, I think:

1. I should have a clustered index on `IndicatorId` and `Interval`. Because of the `ORDER BY`, should it also include `UnixTime`?
2. As I don't have an identity column (didn't create one because I wouldn't use it), I could have a non-clustered primary key on `IndicatorId`, `UnixTime` and `Interval`, because I read that it's always good to have PK on every table.

Also, the data is very rarely deleted, and there are not many updates, but when they happen it's only on 1 row.

Any insight on best practices would be much appreciated.

Comment: *Possibly* you might benefit from a clustered columnstore index, although with so few columns you'd need to test and compare. Have a look at [columnscore.com](https://columnscore.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a site on best practices, this is a site for specific problems. Your best bet is to do some external research on this - cos its a big subject, and really its hard for people to advise without knowing the full details of your system. Then come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: I would go with option 1, the composite clustered index on all three columns. Although all *relational* tables should have a primary key, SQL Server can be used as little more than a storage engine.